# How to parse arguments while running a command line interface?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I'm trying to build a command line interface that is running until exited. What I want to do is let the the user type commands while the interface is running to view functions or call on functions.

I have written a small class that contains two functions that I want a user to be able to invoke: `view_leagues` and `view_season`.

What I want to be able to do is, while the interface is running call the functions using argparse functionality to have positional and optional-arguments.

Example:

Pass below while program is running:
`-v EN_PR` which will invoke `view_seasons()` with the argument `EN_PR`. After it has been invoked the programs continue to run until exited by user.

How can this be done in general?

```
class CLI_Stats():

    def __init__(self):
        self.header = self.header()
        self.description = self.description()
        self.commands = self.commands()
        self.leagues = {'EN_PR': ['2019/2020', '2018/2019'],
                        'EU_CL': ['2019/2020', '2018/2019']}


    @staticmethod
    def header():
        os.system('clear')
        print('\t','*'*60)
        print("\t\t***  Welcome - Football Stats generator  ***")
        print('\t','*'*60)

    @staticmethod
    def description():
        print('Interface to download: \t playerstats \t fixturestats \t team standing \n')
        print('Type "exit" to terminate shell')

    @staticmethod
    def commands():
        commands = {'View Leagues': '-v',
                    'View League Seasons': '-v LEAGUE',
                    'View Stats Type': '-s',
                    'Download stats': '-d LEAGUE SEASON TYPE',
                    'Help' : '-h' }
        for key, value in commands.items():
            print("{: <25} {}".format(key, value))
        print('\n')


    def view_leagues(self):
        leagues = self.leagues
        for league in leagues.keys():
            print("{: <10}".format(league), end="")
        print('\n')

    def view_seasons(self, league):
        if league in self.leagues:
            seasons = self.leagues[league]
            print(league,'seasons:')
            for season in seasons:
                print("{: <20}".format(season), end="")
            print('\n')
        else:
            print(league, 'is not avalible')
            print('\n')

    def parser(self):
        view_leagues = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='View Leagues that exist')
        view_leagues.add_argument('-v', action='store_const', const=self.view_leagues)
        args = view_leagues.parse_args()


def main():
    interface = CLI_Stats()
    while True:
        interface.parser()
```

Comment: `parse_args` can take a list of arguments to parse; `parse_args()` just uses `sys.argv[1:]` by default.

Comment: @chepner How does this work while the program is running? I've seen examples of `parse_args()` when executing a script but no examples of giving args while the script is running

Comment: Supposing you've implemented the functionality with argparse, you could use `shlex` to break up input lines. You could even write a small python program that does `json.dump(sys.argv[1:], sys.stdout)` to have your native shell parse the command. This would only work for single line commands.

Comment: You build whatever list of arguments it is you want to parse. `args = p.parse_args(["-v", "LEAGUE"])`. You can call `parse_args` anytime you want; it's just most *commonly* done early in the script's execution, before you do much more than define the argument parser.

Comment: I've updated the example to illustrate what it is I want to do, as of not it is not functioning